# NSMutableParagraphStyle is ignored with UIKit's NSString draw method

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, nsstring

I'm trying to create a simple `text()` function for an iOS/iPadOS framework that displays text on screen simply at a coordinate. It honors a global `textAlignment` state that can be set to either `.center`, `.left`, or `.right`.

I'm drawing directly to the graphics context.

**Here's the problem:** The function works, but none of the `NSMutableParagraphStyle` attributes are being honored.

```swift
func text(_ string: String, _ x: CGFloat, _ y: CGFloat) {
     let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: string,
                                               attributes: attributes)
     attributedString.draw(at: CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
}
```

`attributes` and `paragraphStyle` are global variables:

```swift
var paragraphStyle: NSMutableParagraphStyle?
var attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [:]
```

They are set by a function that gets called any time a setting is changed:

```swift
func setTextAttributes() {
    paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    
    switch settings.textAlign {
    case .left:
        paragraphStyle?.alignment = .left
    case .right:
        paragraphStyle?.alignment = .right
    case .center:
        paragraphStyle?.alignment = .center
    }
   
    paragraphStyle?.lineSpacing = CGFloat(settings.textLeading)
       
    attributes = [
        .font: UIFont(name: settings.textFont, size: CGFloat(settings.textSize))!,
        .foregroundColor: settings.fill,
        .strokeWidth: -settings.strokeWeight,
        .strokeColor: settings.stroke,
        .paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle!
    ]
}
```

All of the text settings are stored in a settings struct (which I'll omit here) and I've checked the state of both `paragraphStyle` and `attributes` at multiple breakpoints up until the text is drawn. It seems that when it goes into the `NSString` draw method, it simply gets ignored.

Here is some sample code written in the API:

```swift
line(200, 0, 200, height)
line(0, 120, width, 120)
textAlign(.right)
text("ABCD", 200, 120)
line(0, 200, width, 200)
textAlign(.center)
text("EFGH", 200, 200)
textAlign(.left)
line(0, 280, width, 280)
text("IJKL", 200, 280)
```

My output looks like this with everything justified left (with added lines to show that it's all left justified):
[image: Screen capture of iPad simulator with unexpected text layout output.]

Below is more or less what I would expect the output to look like (disregard font change):

[image]

Comment: Can you show what your expected output looks like?

Comment: @Sweeper I added an image of expected behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`draw(in:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/1531631-draw), which lets you specify a `CGRect` in which the drawing will happen.

In each of the alignments, you want to draw the string at an origin that is at a different x-offset from the point passed into the method.

```
func text(_ string: String, _ x: CGFloat, _ y: CGFloat) {
     let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: string,
                                               attributes: attributes)
    let size = attributedString.size()
    let xOffset: CGFloat
    switch attributes[.paragraphStyle]?.alignment ?? .left {
    case .center:
        xOffset = size.width / 2
    case .left:
        xOffset = 0
    case .right:
        xOffset = size.width
    default:
        fatalError("not supported!")
    }
    let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: x - xOffset, y: y). size: size)
    attributedString.draw(in: rect)
}
```

Comment: This is great and address the issue, but to make sure I understand the root cause of the problem: Do UIKit and the NSString draw methods not honor the `NSMutableParagraphStyle` when added as a parameter? Is that why my approach didn't work?

Comment: @rikitikitavi `draw(at:)` is kind of dumb, and always uses left alignment. `draw(in:)` does honor the alignment, but it takes in a `CGRect`. It will align the text correctly inside that rectangle. Try this with multi line text and you’ll see the difference. With a single line, there’s not much to align, is there?